# Comparing elements in the same array

Tags: java

I have this array:

`int[] times ={ 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265, 345, 360, 423 };`

I need to compare the elements together and find and output the largest number. I am using java.

Comment: This is an interesting task. Why did you feel you had to share it with us?

Comment: Google search ideas : "How to compare integers in java", "How to print out in java"

Comment: Off-topic because this is not really a question.

Answer (score 1):

Any ways I am helping because you are purely new to programming
Refer [official java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html)

Don't expect this kind of help for every time :)

```
public class FindMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] times ={ 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265, 345, 360, 423 };
        System.out.println("Max Element: "+ findMax(times));
    }
    //method which takes input as an array of integers and returns max integer
    public static int findMax(int[] nums){
        int max=nums[0];
        for(int num :nums){
            if(max<num){
                max=num;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }


}
```